# Duplicate URL with Spring validation

Tags: validation, spring-mvc

I'm trying to learn Spring MVC 3.0 and I made a simple web to practice the validation. In fact the validations work fine but I can't go to the next web because my code doubles the url of the form. Let me show you, step by step, where is my problem. The url of my form is localhost:8080/ejercicio15/customer but If I introduce a wrong data in the form the url changes to localhost:8080/ejercicio15/customer/signup which is the url of the action attribute in the form and the url of the controller. If I press the button a third time, I get a HTTP 404 error because the url has changed again in localhost:8080/ejercicio15/customer/customer/signup. I gess that this has to be a easy mistake for experts in spring but for a newbie like me this a big headache.

Does someone knows how to solve this mistake?

Thank you in advance for you attention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because you use relative path in `action` attribute, use the full path instead:

```
<c:url var = "action" value = "/customer/signup" />
<form:form action = "${action}" ...>...</form:form>
```